# Security vulnerability for eslint-utils which is added as one of the dependencies for eslint@5.12.0

Tags: security, eslint, yarnpkg, audit, yarn-lock.json

I am getting `Arbitrary Code Execution` security vulnerability for one of the dependencies - `eslint-utils` of package `eslint@5.12.0` in `yarn.lock`. Any leads to upgrade `eslint-utils` to remove the audit vulnerability would be highly appreciated.